# Creating new column with conditional GroupTotals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a dataframe the price/freight/payments can have different treatment depending if they are in multiple or single payments (see image for data example).

[image: Data sample]

My goal is to add new columns with the groupTotal per 'Order id', independently if it has multiple items or multiple payments.

I tried the below but it is taking too long to finish (I aborted after 15min of execution):

```
df_all['fe_price'] = df_all.apply(
    lambda row: df_all['price'].groupby(df_all['order_id']).transform('sum'),
    axis=1
)
```

Is there a better and more performant way to achieve this?

Also, how can I have a conditional statement that understands that in case of multiple payment_sequential, I need to use max and not sum?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks AlexK. For the help with organizing the images and code. I just subscribed and I am still learning how to use the platform!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bad smell. In your lambda function you do not use from your input, in fact you do not use from apply method. Apply method is so slow. You must use directly from groupby.transform method and it produce a series that you can pass it to new column.
In your code you calclulate a groupby.transform operation with same output many times.

Comment: Thanks, Alireza. Indeed getting rid of lambda and using directly from groupby.transform got me the grouptotal per row as I wanted.

Comment: @carribas good luck